# Partition method when using a quicksort for array of integers

Tags: java, sorting, quicksort, partition

I want to be able to sort an array of integers using a QuickSort algorithm but I'm having trouble with my partition method and making use of the pivot. Here is my code with a test method at the bottom.

```
public class QuickSort {

public static  void sort(int [] table) {
   quickSort(table, 0, table.length - 1);
}

private static void quickSort(int [] table,int first,int last) {

    printArray(table);

    if (first < last) {

        int pivIndex = partition(table, first, last);

        System.out.println("pivindex = "+pivIndex);
        quickSort(table, first, pivIndex - 1);


        quickSort(table, pivIndex + 1, last);
    }
}

private static void bubbleSort(int[] table,int first,int last)
{

 int middle = (first + last) / 2;


    if (table[first]>table[middle]) {

        swap(table,first,middle);
    }

 if (table[middle]>table[last]) {

        swap(table,middle,last);
    }

    if (table[middle]<table[first]) {

        swap(table,first,middle);
    }

  swap(table,first,middle);
}

private static int partition(int[] table,int first,int last) {

    bubbleSort(table, first, last);

    Integer pivot = table[0];

    int start = first;
    int end = last;
    while(start<end)
    {
        while((start<last)&&table[start]<=pivot)
        {start++;
        }

        while(table[end]>pivot)
        {
                end--;
        }

        if(start<end)
        {
            swap(table, start, end);

        }
    }
    printArray(table);
    swap(table, first, end);

    return end;        
}
private static  void swap(int [] table, int i, int j) {
    int temp = table[i];
    table[i] = table[j];
    table[j] = temp;
}
private static  void printArray(int [] array) {
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        System.out.print(array[i]);

        if (i < (array.length + 1)) {
            System.out.print(" ");
        }
    }
    System.out.println();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int [] array =  {42,37,45,70,12,19, 39, 43, 61,7,99};
    sort(array);
}

}
```

Comment: What trouble do you have? Please be as specific as possible with your questions.

Comment: when i run the program the array is not printing in ascending order so it hasnt sorted correctly - i need help with the code for getting the partition and sorting to work as what i have done is not correct

Comment: One of your problems is that your partition function calls bubbleSort on the array. That can't work out correctly. You should take another look at your studying material and try to understand what exactly isn't working. StackOverflow is not there to debug your code.